# .AppInstaller (Xelion 8) - Cannot open app package. Failed due to unknown reason

Tags: appinstaller, microsoft-store

Suddenly I have an issue on one laptop that has the Xelion 8 app installed. The company releases the .appinstaller and it normally functions fine on a whole fleet of devices.

What is happening is: I can install the app on the laptop, which then runs the app without any issue. But whenever I close and try to open the app again, I get this error message:

"Cannot open app package.
Reason: Failed due to unknown reason."

This also happens when opening from the search bar or an app icon. The same .appinstaller works fine on the other devices. Online I found the workaround to open the .appinstaller and then choose 'Launch'. This works, but isn't a real solution. And I can't find much substantial about this online.

Someone also mentioned Microsoft fixing this in an appinstaller update, but it didn't help in my case.

Can anyone help? Many thanks